# What is this instrument called and can you give me suggestions which one to buy if i am a beginner?

Tags: instruments, looping

I really want to learn this instrument, but I dont know how it is called those are two youtube videos that people are using the instrument -

and this one

On the second video I know he is using a lot of instruments, but the one I am looking for is the one that can repeat your sounds.

<strike>And as I am a complete beginner what models and brands do you suggest me to buy and practice?</strike> [This part of the question is off-topic]

Comment: There seemed at one point to be consensus that some instrument identification questions should be on topic - https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/why-are-instrument-identification-questions-off-topic. Has there been any development since then?

Comment: @topomorto I see. My read of that meta is that "what type of instrument is this?" is on-topic" and "what exact example of this type of instrument is this?" is not on topic. So if the answer "looper and/or sampler" is acceptable for this asker, then the identification part of this question is on topic, IMHO. If the asker is looking for the exact make and model of something, then that seems to be off topic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that seems a reasonable conclusion - hopefully in this case 'looper/looping' is all the OP needs to start the research process!

Comment: The problem is that there's a ton of electronics there, and knowing what they are won't necessarily lead to knowing how to reproduce the sounds.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, yes, but in my case I am just interested of knowing what is the name of the instrument :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Todd's comment, both of these performers are doing 'live looping', using equipment that you could broadly describe as 'loopers'.

Reggie Watts is using the Electro-Harmonix 2880 Super Multi-track Looper.

I'm not sure what beardyman is using in the video, but there's an article [here](https://djtechtools.com/2012/12/12/the-beardytron-5000-mkii-building-beardymans-ultimate-live-production-system/) about the development of his setup.

It's very hard to recommend specific models, because every performer might need something different from a looper. I've seen some performers create intricate masterpieces using simple loopers, and then there are those performers (like beardyman) who can't find anything off-the-shelf that works for them. I can only recommend doing some reading around about current models of looper, and try to get hold of one for a price that allows you to flip it for something else for not too much of a loss if it doesn't work out (i.e. possibly second hand!).

Comment: It might help to add that there are many devices that are called "samplers" or "performance samplers" that can do looping and much more also.

Comment: The most "famous" one (in the sense of "number of people that have heard music made using it"), is probably Ed Sheeran's *Chewie Monsta II*, although that is a purpose-built one-of-a-kind (technically two-of-a-kind for redundancy) piece of kit made specifically for him (and with the design heavily influenced by him).

Answer (score -2):

If you indeed want a 'buffet (of sound) in a box' then look at this ... OP-1.

https://www.teenageengineering.com/products/op-1

Is it for a beginner?

It's incredible what folks are doing with this.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChnxLLvzviaR5NeKOevB8iQ